# ldd on the binary not showing my shared library

Tags: shared-libraries, ldd

I link a shared library on the command line while building an executable. Running `ldd` on that executable is not showing the linked shared library.

After looking at some of the output of the linker, I have even tried adding the `-Wl,--no-as-needed` option and that didn't help either.

foo.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo () {
    printf ("Hello world\n");
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    printf ("In main \n");
    foo ();
}
```

Here's the command I used to compile and link:

```
$ gcc -Wl,--no-as-needed main.c -o main -L./ -lfoo
/bin/ld: cannot find -lfoo
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

$ gcc -c foo.c -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so -o libfoo.so

$ ls -l libfoo.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 apple eng 1488 Jun  4 04:44 libfoo.so

$ gcc -Wl,--no-as-needed main.c -o main -L./ -lfoo

$ ldd main
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffbdd6c000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6367e23000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005556e268a000)
```

`libfoo.so` does not show up above.

```
$ objdump -x main | grep NEEDED
  NEEDED               libc.so.6
```

Why isn't `libfoo.so` showing up as `NEEDED`?

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: Version of `gcc`? Exit code of `ldd main`? (Run `ldd main; echo $?`)

Comment: uname -a
Linux myhost-165 3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Dec 28 14:23:39 EST 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: ldd main;echo $?
 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc17f98000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f00ed6f2000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000560462687000)
0

Comment: @Apad Please add these details to your question. The formatting of this output in comments is horrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the gcc option `-c` you're telling it to create only object from `foo.c`, so the only product you're getting from this gcc command is an *object file*. The fact that its suffix is `.so` is only because you forced it using `-o` option. If you run this command without `-o` you'd see that the output is just `foo.o` - an object file.

If you omit the `-c` from the gcc command you'd get the shared object you wanted.

Running `file` on the output file shows the difference (note that I'm not setting the output name using `-o` and letting gcc use its default names):

With `-c`:

```
> gcc -c foo.c -shared
> file foo.o
foo.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

Without `-c`:

```
> gcc foo.c -shared
> file a.out
a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=a63581bfc45f845c501ffb6635, not stripped
                                                                  ^^^
                                                                  |||
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. That helped.

Comment: @Apad If this answer helped you, click the check mark below the vote count to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This command does *not* generate a shared library:

```
gcc -c foo.c -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so -o libfoo.so
```

It generates an object file `libfoo.so` that is later *statically* linked with your code. Proof: remove the `lib` file, the program will still run.

**Solution:**

Compile the object file separately, then convert it into a shared library. You will have to tell the loader where to search for the shared libraries by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
gcc -c foo.c 
gcc foo.o -shared -o libfoo.so
gcc main.c -o main -L./ -lfoo
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`
ldd ./main 
#   linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe0f7cb000)
#   libfoo.so => /home/---/tmp/libfoo.so (0x00007f9bab6ec000)
#   libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9bab2fb000)
#   /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9babaf0000)
```